# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir ciertos campos de una línea?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Tengo un archivo de este estilo:

```
primerparametro; segundoparametro; 6 para0r; 
primerparametro; segundoparametro; 3 para0e; 
primerparametro; segundoparametro; 6 para0r;
primerparametro; segundoparametro; 4 para0f;
primerparametro; segundoparametro; 6 para0h; 
primerparametro; segundoparametro; 2 para0j;
primerparametro; segundoparametro; 1 para04;
```

Los parámetros están separados por ";". Quiero imprimir el primer y el último parámetro con grep, para que me dé algo así como:

```
primerparametro; 6 para0r; 
primerparametro; 3 para0e; 
...
```

La orden de búsqueda sería algo así:

```
grep -Eio '[a-z0-9._-]*+; | [0-9]+[ ]+para+[a-z0-9]{2}+;' archivo.txt;
```

Sin embargo, lo que yo no quiero es que aparezca el segundo parámetro en los resultados.

Comment: Sería interesante que aportaras un [mcve]. Es decir, un ejemplo más o menos real junto con la salida que querrías. Por otra parte, `grep` no parece lo más adecuado para esto; puedes retorcerlo para conseguirlo, pero es algo que `awk` haría fantásticamente.

Comment: Pienso lo mismo que @fedorqui . Ese texto y patrón no son un buen ejemplo. Por otro lado, ¿has probado a usar `cut` o `sed`? La funcionalidad de `grep` está limitada a mostrar sólo el texto coincidente o la línea completa, no te permite eliminar contenido intermedio.

Comment: Lo había puesto mal, ya lo he corregido.

Comment: Pero Isaac, ¿cuál es la salida que quieres? Dices _quiero buscar_ y luego _que muestre_. ¿Quieres filtrar líneas o mostrarlas todas pero solamente algunos campos?

Comment: Mostrar: `primerparametro; 2 para0j;` Por cada linea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existen diversas maneras de llevar a cabo tu tarea dependiendo de qué harás con cada uno de los registros obtenidos.

## [`awk`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)

El procesador de texto `awk` te permite configurar `FS` (field separator, o separador de campos) y `OFS` (output field separator, separador de campos de salida) para obtener los campos de cada línea y mostrarlos:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} {print $1,$3}' archivo.txt
```

`BEGIN` te permite definir un bloque de código que se ejecutará al comienzo. En este caso es asignar como separador de campo de entrada y de salida el carácter `;` (`{FS=OFS=";"}`).

El segundo bloque (`{print $1, $3}`) se ejecuta por cada línea de datos y muestra los campos 1 y 3 separados por el separador de salida `OFS` (`;`).

Nota: esta es la misma solución propuesta por [fedorqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui) en esta [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/136294/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-imprimir-ciertos-campos-de-una-l%C3%ADnea/#answer-136309).

## [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)

No se necesita un procesador pesado como `awk` para realizar la tarea, una sencilla solución es la que te propuse en los comentarios, usando `cut` de la siguiente manera:

```
cut -d ';' -f 1,3 archivo.txt
```

La herramienta `cut` te permite mostrar los campos que desees con el parámetro `-f` (en este caso, primer y tercer parámetro) y usar el delimitador que prefieras (en este caso `;`, entrecomillado para que no lo considere final de instrucción).

## [`read`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

También se puede usar la función interna `read` que permite leer datos de la corriente de entrada y separarlos por su `IFS`:

```
while IFS=";" read -r a b c ; do echo "$a;$c" ; done < archivo.txt
```

El bucle `while` se ejecutará mientras siga recibiendo datos la función `read` línea a línea desde el archivo `archivo.txt`, asignando los valores a las variables `a`, `b` y `c` separando la línea haciendo uso del separador configurado en `IFS`, mostrando únicamente los campos `a` y `c` (primero y tercero) en la salida separados por un punto y coma en el `echo`.

## [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

La herramienta `sed` es muy compleja, pero tiene usos bastante sencillos como el siguiente:

```
sed -r 's/^([^;]*;)[^;]*;/\1/' archivo.txt
```

Uso el modificador `s` para sustituir los patrones encontrados de la siguiente manera:

- `^`: empezamos desde el comienzo de cada línea.
- `([^;]*;)`: primer bloque (`\1`), desde el comienzo de línea coincide con todo lo que no sea un punto y coma (`^;`) e incluye en el bloque el punto y coma encontrado.
- `[^;]*;`: segunda parte de la búsqueda que no será almacenada como bloque y que será descartada (no se usará en la sustitución, por lo tanto se eliminará). Cualquier carácter hasta el próximo (segundo) punto y coma.
- `\1`: Sustituye los dos bloques anteriores por sólo el primero de ellos. El resto de la línea (tercer y demás parámetros) se mantendrán intactos.

## Rendimiento

Comparación del rendimiento:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 1000000) ; do echo "primer parametro; segundo parametro; num $i" >> archivo.txt ; done

$ time awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} {print $1,$3}' archivo.txt | tail -n 3
primer parametro; num 999998
primer parametro; num 999999
primer parametro; num 1000000

real    0m1.439s
user    0m1.308s
sys 0m0.120s

$ time cut -d ';' -f 1,3 archivo.txt | tail -n 3
primer parametro; num 999998
primer parametro; num 999999
primer parametro; num 1000000

real    0m0.217s
user    0m0.148s
sys 0m0.084s

$ time ( while IFS=";" read -r a b c ; do echo "$a;$c" ; done < archivo.txt ) | tail -n 3
primer parametro; num 999998
primer parametro; num 999999
primer parametro; num 1000000

real    0m27.135s
user    0m25.200s
sys 0m4.268s

$ time sed -r 's/^([^;]*;)[^;]*;/\1/' archivo.txt | tail -n 3
primer parametro; num 999998
primer parametro; num 999999
primer parametro; num 1000000

real    0m6.354s
user    0m6.384s
sys 0m0.152s
```

El ganador en este ejemplo es, por clara ventaja, la herramienta `cut`.

Comment: Tanto `cut` como `awk` son herramientas externas, por lo que la _pesadez_ es equivalente. Si quisieras mejorar este aspecto, podrías utilizar _builtins_ como _read_.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta con un ejemplo práctico de mi argumento. También la herramienta `grep` es una herramienta externa. Y sí, es cierto que `read` también hace el trabajo. Lo compararé.

Comment: Interesante análisis, +1 por ello. Sea como fuere, la pesadez de awk/cut/sed/grep para una tarea trivial como esta creo que es un argumento más académico que otra cosa.

Comment: Estoy probando y con ese archivo con un millón de registros ha durado muchísimo más. Voy a editar la respuesta con todas ellas. Gracias por el comentario.

Comment: Aunque luego es bueno tener en cuenta lo descrito en [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/40596)

Comment: He puesto un ejemplo de cada caso y comparado el rendimiento de cada uno, creo que dependiendo del caso una opción es mejor que otra. Pero siempre depende de qué se quiera hacer con los datos.

Comment: No puedo dejar de comentar que la opción awk es exactamente la que yo propuse. No tengo ningún inconveniente en que la menciones en tu comparativa, pero lo correcto sería indicarlo siguiendo las reglas del copyright de SO . Dicho lo cual: gran currada, Oscar, olé por ello. Realmente `cut` es la solución más óptima para estos casos.

Comment: Tu respuesta también es acertada, pero le dejé el comentario y no me respondió, así que no he podido ver tu respuesta hasta hoy (que también llevas mi +1 por tu trabajo). Quería ofrecerle mi alternativa dependiendo de qué quisiera hacer con los datos. Ahora estaba editando también con `sed`. Edito: he agregado referencia a tu respuesta y a su autor.

Comment: Hola gracias por la explicación la verdad que el rendimiento en este caso no era un factor importante, pero es bueno saber que cut, es más idóneo para lo que quería conseguir.

Comment: @IsaacPalacio de hecho yo te recomendaría que marcaras esta respuesta como aceptada, pues es más completa e incluye mi respuesta. Por tanto, aceptándola ayudarás a destacar tanto la respuesta "útil" como el detalle de cuál es la más "conveniente" en términos de rendimiento.

Comment: Ok, ya lo hecho. b

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui por la edición, he eliminado la bandera de búsqueda global (`/g`) de la prueba de rendimiento y actualizados los tiempos (mejorados ligeramente al no tener que buscar más coincidencias tras encontrar la primera). Gracias @Isaac, me alegra que te sirviera la respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Quieres coger un fichero con campos separados por ";" e imprimir alguno de ellos.

Esto es trivial con `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {print $1, $3}' fichero
primerparametro; 6 para0r
primerparametro; 3 para0e
primerparametro; 6 para0r
primerparametro; 4 para0f
primerparametro; 6 para0h
primerparametro; 2 para0j
primerparametro; 1 para04
```

Con `BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}` estamos diciéndole a Awk que el separador de campos es el punto y coma.

Después, nos limitamos a escribir el primero y el tercero.

Si quieres el punto y coma final también puedes imprimir el cuarto campo, que está vacío pero aún así computa:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {print $1, $3, $4}' fichero
primerparametro; 6 para0r; 
...
```

Si las condiciones no están basadas en la posición de los campos, sino en el formato, ya deberíamos utilizar sed y eliminar cosas en función de esas condiciones. Para ello necesitaríamos saber con más detalle cómo es tu fichero.

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui